# Difference between ClientSession and Session in TensorFlow C++ API

Tags: c++, tensorflow

TensorFlow r1.0 C++ API comes with `Session` and `ClientSession` classes. Some of the examples shipping with TensorFlow use `ClientSession` and others use `Session`. Do these two different types of session use the same underlying mechanism under the hood or is one of the preferred over another? The syntax for using them is a bit different but other than that are there any differences in behavior?

Answer (score 14):

In TensorFlow's C++ API, the [`tensorflow::Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/client-session) API is a low-level interface that deals with serialized `GraphDef` protocol buffers and provides a string-based interface for running subgraphs.

By contrast, the [`tensorflow::ClientSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/client-session) API is higher level, and integrates with the new C++ API for building TensorFlow graphs—much in the same way as the Python [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph) and [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) classes do.

Therefore, you will probably want to use a `tensorflow::ClientSession` if you are building the graph with the C++ API, but the `tensorflow::Session` interface is easier to use if you already have a serialized `GraphDef` (representing e.g. a pre-trained model) and just want to run inference on that model.

Comment: I wish `tensorflow::Session` was documented :(

Comment: There's quite a lot of documentation in the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/public/session.h). Feel free to open a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) or propose a change in a [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pulls) if there are details you'd like to see added!