# How to use the tensorflow C++ API DirectSession class for an asynchonous queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, session, tensorflow

I want to share a tensorflow FIFOQueue using the C++ API where a producer and consumer are running asynchronously (as very briefly discussed here in a python context: [TensorFlow C++, runtime issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346117/tensorflow-c-runtime-issue)). I have the impression that I need to use DirectSession and its thread pooling support (as discussed here: [Changing the number of threads in TensorFlow on Cifar10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389945/changing-the-number-of-threads-in-tensorflow-on-cifar10)).  So the direct_session_test.cc file with the examples 
 using BlockingOp and BlockingOpState look like they might be a good template.

But direct_session.h marks important methods as experimental (especially .Run()) so any tips and advice on proceeding would be welcome.

Note that DirectSession has very little documentation including the header direct_session.h.  Some of the differences between tensorflow's other C++ Session classes (e.g. Session, ClientSession Interactive) are discussed elsewhere:

This thread compares Session and ClientSession: 
[Difference between ClientSession and Session in TensorFlow C++ API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603821/difference-between-clientsession-and-session-in-tensorflow-c-api)

This thread compares Session and InteractiveSession: 
[difference between tf.Session() and tf.InteractiveSession()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791469/difference-between-tf-session-and-tf-interactivesession)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use DirectSession directly. ClientSession should be good enough, and its thread pool can be configured via the configproto as usual.

Comment: Good to hear that ClientSession is sufficient.  But it remains how to deal with the contention of the FIFOQueue node from the producer and consumer nodes with a lock (mutex).  The direct_session_test.cc gives an idea with the BlockingOp, but this queue example seems like a useful use case that could have a more specific example. Any suggestions?

Comment: The FIFOQueue has an internal mutex. Why do you need another one?

Comment: Right, thanks, the mutex is available at the C++ API level (unlike the Python level which seems to require the use of QueueRunner).  An example of its use in an asynchonous consumer/producer context  would be very helpful. For example should EnqueueOp and DequeueOp be used or should the FIFOQueue.TryEnqueue() and Try?

Comment: TryDequeue() be used?

Comment: The python level doesn't require the use of QueueRunner. A QueueRunner is just a python thread calling session.run(queue.enqueue()) in an infinite* loop.